# Fill a 1 min Dateframe column from another 1 day Dateframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to pandas and time series analysis. So bear with me if I'm missing something very obvious.

I have 2 data frames. df1 is in 1 day time frame and df2 is in 1 min time frame. I want to insert new column in df2 and fill same data for all rows for a given day from df1.

df 1 :

```
    Date         Range

0   2020-03-01   50
1   2020-03-02   5
2   2020-03-03   20
3   2020-03-04   15
```

df 2 :

```
    Date          
0   2020-03-01 09:55:00 
1   2020-03-01 09:56:00
2   2020-03-01 09:57:00  
3   2020-03-01 09:58:00
    .......
    .......
    .......
n   2020-03-04 03:15:00
```

Expected Result :

df 2 :

```
    Date                   Range

0   2020-03-01 09:55:00    50
1   2020-03-01 09:56:00    50
2   2020-03-01 09:57:00    50
3   2020-03-01 09:58:00    50
    .......
    .......
    .......
n   2020-03-04 03:15:00    15
```

EDIT 1 :

1 min data frame have other column data too and I just wanna merge this particular `Range` data from 1 day df to 1 min df.

EDIT 2 :

Both df1 and df2 have date as their index.

1 min df looks like this :

[image: 1 min df]

1 day df looks like this :

[image: 1 day df]

All I'm trying to do is insert this `Range` column from 1 day df in to 1 min df for all rows in same day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df2['date']=pd.to_datetime(df2.index.date)
```

You can do this by using `merge()` method:-

```
pd.merge(df2.reset_index(),df1.reset_index(),left_on='date',right_on='Date',suffixes=('_df2','_df1'))
```

**Note:-** The above code do `inner join` and if you want `left join` then just pass `how` parameter and set that equal to left

```
pd.merge(df2.reset_index(),df1.reset_index(),left_on='date',right_on='Date',suffixes=('_df2','_df1'),how='left')
```

Comment: Getting 'AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!' coz i use datetime object for data in "Date" column. So any idea on how could i solve this.

Comment: Updated Answer...kindly have a look...btw you are getting this error because I think that the Date columns in your both df's are of type Object

Comment: Tried ur solution but thing is my date column is set as index in both df so this is throwing an `KeyError: 'Date'`. I have updated the question in  details. Kindly check

Comment: Doing like u suggested make me to lose time value in my df indexes. I don't wanna to lose that time information. And also is there a way to merge `Range` column alone since i don't want to merge other columns from my 1 day df to my 1 min df

Comment: Thank u man i solved it by saving existing time value in another variable and doing merging . Then setting time value to index of df.

Comment: I also updated my answer btw its identically same that you done..